# How to add temp data to Telerik MVC Grid before save in the repository?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, telerik

Some time ago I developed a asp.net webforms app using Devexpress component, in aspxgridview I could insert rows in my grid just using the client side and not saving it in my db. After the user insert all the rows that he needs, the user press the "send" button and I then I send all the data to my serverside saving in the Db.

now in my MVC Telerik grid, I can't figure out how to do the same thing.
Here's my view:

```
  @(Html.Telerik()
      .Grid( Model )
      .Name( "DocumentGrid" )
      .DataKeys(a => a.Add(b=> b.IDDocument))
                      .ToolBar(commands => { commands.Insert().Text("add"); })
                      .Columns(c =>
                                   {                                         
                                       c.Bound(column => column.SupplierIdentification).Title("CNPJ/CPF");
                                       c.Bound(column => column.StatusDescription).Title("Status");                                           
                                       c.Bound(column => column.ExpirationDate).Title("Vencimento");
                                       c.Bound(column => column.IsStock).Title("Estoque");)
                                   .DataBinding(x => 
                                       x.Server().Insert("InsertNewDocument","Client"))
      .Editable(a => a.Mode(GridEditMode.InForm).TemplateName("AddDocumentModel")).ClientEvents(x => x.OnSave("onSave")))
```

As you can see, I have a Insert that calls an action with my model as parameter, but I would like to 'fire' that Action just when I finish to add rows to the grid.

Here's my JavaScript button placed on my custom edit Template:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="OnUpdateClick(this)"><b>Confirm</b>
```

This button should call a OnUpdateClick function which does the insert of the temp row to my grid.

```
function OnUpdateClick() {
    var grid = $("#DocumentGrid").data("tGrid");
    var item = {};
    grid.insertRow(item);
}
```

It should be something like this I guess.
Any suggestions?

EDIT:

When I Edit my grid I get the edit template from the ~/Shared/EditorTemplates  folder, is it possible to get my grid data from a Script in the EditorTemplate folder?

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you make it simpler by using Ajax Databinding and Grid Operation Mode as Client.

This is what I had done on project, so I can basically bulk update and bulk add items in the client side and it only uploads to the server on save.  Should be something like this.

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<YourViewModel>()
.Name("DocumentGrid")
.Columns(c =>
{
    c.Bound(column => column.SupplierIdentification).Title("CNPJ/CPF");
    c.Bound(column => column.StatusDescription).Title("Status");                                           
    c.Bound(column => column.ExpirationDate).Title("Vencimento");
    c.Bound(column => column.IsStock).Title("Estoque");
    c.Bound(a => a.IDDocument).Hidden()
})
.DataBinding(d => 
    d.Ajax()
        .OperationMode(GridOperationMode.Client)
        .Select("SelectAction", "YourController")
        .Update("UpdateAction", "YourController")
        .Insert("InsertAction", "YourController")
        .Delete("DeleteAction", "YourController")
    )
.Pageable(p => p.PageSize(50))
.Sortable()
.Scrollable()
.Groupable()
.Filterable()
.KeyboardNavigation()
.Resizable(r => r.Columns(true))
.Reorderable(r => r.Columns(true))
.Editable(e => 
    e.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell)
            .DataKeys(k => k.Add(a => a.IDDocument))
            .ToolBar(c => 
            {
                c.Insert();
                c.SubmitChanges();
            })
    )
)
```

Your actions will look something like this

```
[HttpPost]
[GridAction]
public ActionResult UpdateAction([Bind(Prefix = "updated")]IEnumerable<YourViewModel> updatedTransactions)
{
...
}

[HttpPost]
[GridAction]
public ActionResult InsertAction([Bind(Prefix = "inserted")]IEnumerable<YourViewModel> insertedTransactions)
{
...
}

[HttpPost]
[GridAction]
public ActionResult DeleteAction([Bind(Prefix = "deleted")]IEnumerable<YourViewModel> deletedTransactions)
{
...
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. What i exactly get with this [Bind(Prefix = "deleted")]IEnumerable<YourViewModel> parameter?

Comment: Every deleted item, so up to you how you handle them.  Same goes with other IEnumerable parameters.